# How do I know if a value of an element inside an array was changed?

Tags: arrays, swift, valuechangelistener

**Language Used:** Swift 2.3

For example I have a model called `Doctor`

```
class Doctor {
    var name = ""
    var number = 123
    init(name:String, number:String) { 
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
    }
}
```

And in another class I made it into an array

```
class SomeClass {
    var doctors:[Doctor] = [
        Doctor(name: "Matt Smith", number: 11),
        Doctor(name: "David Tennant", number: 10),
        Doctor(name: "Peter Capaldi", number: 12)
    ]
}
```

And then for some reason I decide to change the value of `index` #2

```
class SomeClass {
    ...
    // let's just say that this code was executed inside the code somewhere....
    func change() {
        doctors[2].name = "Good Dalek"
        // or
        doctors[2] = Doctor(name: "Christopher Eccleston", number: 9)
    }
    ...
}
```

How will I know that the value of the `doctors` Array is not the same as before?

I do know of `filter` and `sort` functions. I also know how to use `didSet` such that I could do this

```
var doctors:[Doctor] = [] {
    didSet {
        // do something if `doctors` was changed
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest thing you can do is not to allow such a situation. Make the name a constant (`let`) or make `Doctor` into a `struct`. The concept of immutables is very powerful and it simplifies design a lot.

Comment: But I need to observe changes inside the Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, by letting `doctors` array to be as [property observer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html):

```
class Doctor {
    var name = ""
    var number = 123
    init(name:String, number:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
    }
}


class SomeClass {
    var doctors: [Doctor] = [
        Doctor(name: "Matt Smith", number: 11),
        Doctor(name: "David Tennant", number: 10),
        Doctor(name: "Peter Capaldi", number: 12)
        ] {
        didSet {
            print("doctros array has been modifed!")
        }
    }
}


let someClass = SomeClass()
someClass.doctors[0] = Doctor(name: "New Doctor", number: 13) // "doctros array has been modifed!"

someClass.doctors.append(Doctor(name: "Appended Doctor", number: 13)) // "doctros array has been modifed!"

someClass.doctors.remove(at: 0) // "doctros array has been modifed!"
```

Note that each of adding, editing or deleting operations affects `doctors` array calls the `didSet` code (`print("doctros array has been modifed!")`).

Comment: but will that trigger if only a property inside doctors[0] was changed?

Comment: I know that didSet will trigger if I append a value to doctors[0]

Comment: @ZonilyJame didSet should be called if you added a new doctor or modified an existed doctor.

Comment: That seems like a way to do it. if I'd like to modify one object I'd just remove it at said index and then insert at said index. works but not the way I imagined it to work haha

Comment: @ZonilyJame you might also want check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120656/how-can-i-observe-a-specific-element-with-swift-collection-types-using-property) and their answers for observing a specific element in the array.